# Decorate response model of a FastAPI route with another model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a common response pattern for most of the routes, like having specific fields in it (e.g. 'date' with default value, 'info', where decorated data should live in and so on).

For example, having this endpoint:

`@route.get(...,response_model=Entry)` endpoint returns serialized `Entry` object.

Would it be possible to declare a pydantic model, like `CommonResponse`, that automatically contains predefined fields and put `Entry` model in its field('info'), and use like this:

`@route.get(...,response_model=CommonResponse[Entry])` or `@route.get(...,response_model=CommonResponse[List[Entry]])`

Comment: @larsks that works, but i have lots of entities and routes, so i'm in search of a more "elegant" solution. Moreover, there would be several types of 'CummonResponse'.

UPD: the proposed solution was to declare separate classes for different types of response classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [pydantic doc- Generic Models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#generic-models)

> Pydantic supports the creation of generic models to make it easier to reuse a common model structure.

1. define generic model

```py
DataT = TypeVar('DataT')


class GenericResponseModel(GenericModel, Generic[DataT]):
    success: bool = Field(True)
    error_msg: Optional[str] = Field(None, alias='errorMsg')
    data: Optional[DataT] = Field(None)
    total: Optional[int] = Field(None)

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

2. Use in your `response_model`

```py
@router.get('/',
         response_model=schemas.GenericResponseModel[List[schemas.ShopModel]])
# ...

@router.get('/{shop_id}',
            response_model=schemas.GenericResponseModel[schemas.ShopModel])
async def get():
    # ...
    shop = get_shop()
    return schemas.GenericResponseModel(data=shop)
```

3. The openapi doc will cantains `List[schemas.ShopModel]` or `schemas.ShopModel` and have example value for these

Comment: How does pydantic know how to populate this model? How can it know what maps to total or even error_msg?